# Why when I upload file with apollo-server the file is uploaded but the file is 0kb?

Tags: file-upload, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, apollostack

I tried to solve the problem but I don't understand why the file is uploaded but his size is 0Kb.
I see this code in the tutorial  but he works on that tutorial but, is not worked for me

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type File {
    url: String!
  }

  type Query {
    hello: String!
  }

  type Mutation {
    fileUpload(file: Upload!): File!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello world!',
  },
  Mutation: {
    fileUpload: async (_, { file }) => {
      const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;
      const stream = createReadStream();
      const pathName = path.join(__dirname, `/public/images/${filename}`);
      await stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathName));

      return {
        url: `http://localhost:4000/images/${filename}`,
      };
    },
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

---

then when I upload the file, it is uploaded, but the file is 0kb

---

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw1iC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the resolver is returning before the file has uploaded, causing the server to respond before the client has finished uploading. You need to promisify and await the file upload stream events in the resolver.

Here is an example:

https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-examples/blob/c456f86b58ead10ea45137628f0a98951f63e239/api/server.js#L40-L41

In your case:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => "Hello world!",
  },
  Mutation: {
    fileUpload: async (_, { file }) => {
      const { createReadStream, filename } = await file;
      const stream = createReadStream();
      const path = path.join(__dirname, `/public/images/${filename}`);

      // Store the file in the filesystem.
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Create a stream to which the upload will be written.
        const writeStream = createWriteStream(path);

        // When the upload is fully written, resolve the promise.
        writeStream.on("finish", resolve);

        // If there's an error writing the file, remove the partially written
        // file and reject the promise.
        writeStream.on("error", (error) => {
          unlink(path, () => {
            reject(error);
          });
        });

        // In Node.js <= v13, errors are not automatically propagated between
        // piped streams. If there is an error receiving the upload, destroy the
        // write stream with the corresponding error.
        stream.on("error", (error) => writeStream.destroy(error));

        // Pipe the upload into the write stream.
        stream.pipe(writeStream);
      });

      return {
        url: `http://localhost:4000/images/${filename}`,
      };
    },
  },
};
```

Note that it’s probably not a good idea to use the filename like that to store the uploaded files, as future uploads with the same filename will overwrite earlier ones. I'm not really sure what will happen if two files with the same name are uploaded at the same time by two clients.